# Erase data stored in memory or simplified this sub further?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

I'm having an issue somewhere in this sub when I run it.  I call it up through another sub, but my entire pc crashes somewhere during this routine.

1- is there a way to simplify it further than I already have, and

2- I can't find the command to erase anything stored in memory before this point or somewhere I can insert something similar in this code if it is appropriate to do so.

```
Sub Splitbook()
Dim xPath As String, xWs As Worksheet, Box As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Box = Application.InputBox("Set?")

For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If xWs.Name <> "Master" Then
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & " " & Box & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Else

    End If
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Sorry in advance if this isn't an appropriate topic.

Comment: You are looping through each worksheet of a workbook. Lets say it has 2 sheets and neither are named "master". The first sheet you `.copy` and then you save the `activeworkbook`. Then you close the `activeworkbook`. Then it iterates to the second sheet of the now closed workbook... that seems like not what you intended to have happen. Perhaps you don't want to close the `activeworkbook` until after the loop has finished? Also... why `.Copy` the worksheet. You never paste it anywhere. That seems superfluous.

Comment: So the file that this runs on usually has 96 tabs.  95 of them are just a store number, then the 96th is the "master" with all of the information.  The goal of this is to break each tab into a separate file.  You're correct on the `xWS.Copy` line; that should be removed.  As for the `ActiveWorkbook` lines, are you saying the first one in the `if` statement is the only one that is needed?

Comment: I worry that all of this "ActiveWorkbook" is causing the issue. Above your `for` loop put `Set xWB = ActiveWorkbook`. Then your `For` loop can look like `For Each xWs In xWB.Sheets`. KEep the rest of the code as-is and see if that keeps it from crashing.

Comment: Attempting now.  I should note though that 75% of the time this works perfectly.  When I have several programs open while running this is when the PC crashes.

Comment: It ran, but I haven't been able to reproduce the crash when I want to.  Removing any other part of the original code I supplied does not complete as desired though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try using VBA.DoEvents. the problem you have may due to using lots of system memory since you are opening and close excel workbook. When you have too many workbooks in circulation your original excel becomes "not responding"
using VBA.DoEvents may slow down overall speed but should preventing the original workbook to be "not responding"

```
For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If xWs.Name <> "Master" Then
vba.DoEvents
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & " " & Box & _
".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Else

End If
Next
```

Comment: I just tested this and it did run to completion.  Your answer is definitely on the track that I was looking for as I assumed it was a system memory issue causing my crashes.  I'll have to use this solution a few more times to be 100% sure it has fixed the problem, but I feel like you answered my question.  Thanks!